# ASP.NET WebApi: IQueryable support with MongoDB official C# driver

Tags: mongodb, iqueryable, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to implement Api Controller which gets data from MongoDB. It would be nice to support IQueryable interface for OData when C# driver since version 1.4 supports LINQ.

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
  private MongoCollection<User> collection;

  public UserController()
  {
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mongo"].ConnectionString;
    var database = MongoDatabase.Create(connectionString);
    this.collection = database.GetCollection<User>("users");
  }

  public IQueryable<User> Get()
  {
    return this.collection.AsQueryable<User>();
  }
}
```

When I am trying to get users I receive following exception:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: Unable to find root IQueryable

Does anybody know what is the reason?

Comment: Driver Issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-419?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Achangehistory-tabpanel

Comment: Workaround is to add so extra expression: return this.collection.AsQueryable<User>().Select(u => u);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in asp.net mvc 4 release.
Great implementation:
http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/supporting-odata-inlinecount-with-the-new-web-api-odata-preview-package/